# Iterating over a large number of xml documents

Tags: python, xml, list, loops, beautifulsoup

I have a list of roughly 56,000 xml documents that I each need to open and pull out an attribute and verify the attributes value against another list (csv file)

At the moment I am using this, which works for one xml document

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(xmlText)
nameTag = soup.find('instrument', {"name": True})
idTag = soup.find('instrument', {"id": True})
print(idTag['id'] + "," + nameTag['name'])
```

this gives me the id and the name of the item, which I can then compare against my other list.
But with 56,000 of these documents, what's the best way to deal with this?
I will need to download each document then load it into BeautifulSoup and pull out the name and id. Can I do all that in a simple for loop?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a large number of downloads (and high network latency), I would recommend using a library to get the xml page (many such packages/libraries exist to do this) and pass the text directly into the BeautifulSoup parser.  I'm guessing the network will most likely be the bottleneck here, so I would recommend that you look into a concurrency package/library so that you can process pages while downloading other ones (look at `multiprocessing.map_async`, or something similar).  Having said that, you could do it in a for loop (if you already have the names) and process the serially, at the expense of running time.

This is a rough outline on what you could do, but I won't be providing code since concurrency can get messy and I don't have much time at the moment.